# Angular Development Docker Container

Tags: angular, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to create a docker container to use for Angular development.

Using a nearly identical dockerfile to the one below, I was able to create a development container for React.

```
FROM node:8.9.0

ENV NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL warn
ARG app_env
ENV APP_ENV $app_env

RUN mkdir -p /app1
WORKDIR /app1
COPY ./app1 ./

COPY app1/package.json /app1

RUN npm install
RUN npm update
RUN npm install -g typescript

EXPOSE 4200

RUN chmod a+x /app1/node_modules/.bin/*

ENTRYPOINT ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
#ENTRYPOINT npm start
```

To run the container I use:

```
docker run -i -t -p 4200:4200 -v /var/react/{your app name}/{Your apps sub folder}/src:/{ Your apps sub folder } /src {container ID}
```

I then enter the container and run `npm start` or `npm start 0.0.0.0:4200`. Everything compiles successfully and says it should be running on `localhost:4200` but I get a connection refused error.

***I'll reiterate, using an identical dockerfile, I am able to do this with react. The only differences between the files are port numbers and mounted volumes.***

As such, this makes me think it's something to do with the Angular configuration but I don't know where to begin looking. Any ideas?

thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As I suspected, it was an Angular config issue. All I needed to do was change my `package.json` file.

From:

`"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve"`

To:

`"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check"`

My Dockerfile stayed the same.

Answer (score 3):

Hi there are simple steps to build and run docker file in your angular Project

1) create a .dockerignore file and add node_modules
.git into it

2) add Dockerfile with

```
FROM node:8.6 as node
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app/
RUN npm install
COPY ./ /app/
ARG env=prod
RUN npm run build -- --prod --environment $env

# Stage 1, based on Nginx, to have only the compiled app, ready for production with Nginx
FROM nginx:1.13
COPY --from=node /app/dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./nginx-custom.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

3) Build your image using the production configuration (the default), e.g.:

```
docker build -t my-angular-project:prod .
```

mind the dot at the end of the line

4) Build your image using the development environment (no configuration), e.g.:

```
docker build -t my-angular-project:dev --build-arg configuration="" .
```

5) Test your image for the production environment (production configuration) with:

```
docker run -p 80:80 my-angular-project:prod
```

6) Open your browser in http://localhost.

7) Test your image for the development environment (no configuration) with:

```
docker run -p 80:80 my-angular-project:dev
```

hope these steps help you to run your docker file

Comment: Awesome, I'll give these a try and let you know how it works. Thanks!

Comment: It threw an error on `COPY --from=node /app/dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html` and it would have thrown an error on this line `COPY ./nginx-custom.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`. In both cases, neither files exist. This might be a dumb question but is the dist folder automatically created with the project? I don't have one in my app. Also, the nginx-custom file, where is this coming from?

Comment: Oops sorry you can remove those line as that was for ngnix deployment and no dist folder is not created automatically you need to run ng build —prod

Comment: ok, I'll remove those. Lastly, is the dockerignore file needed? Why wouldn't I want the node_modules in there?

Comment: Yes it is need beacause when you will build image node modules files will also be included to skip this we need to add node modules in that file

Comment: I appreciate your help but I am still unable to get the app to run. I get the `NG Live Development Server is listening at localhost:4200` message but when I go `hostname:4200` I don't get anything. Is there anything that I need to change in the Angular config files?

Comment: Does anyone know why `RUN npm run build --prod` doesn't work but `RUN npm run build -- --prod` does?